# Combine dropzone with textarea

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Is there a way to combine dropzone with an editable form textarea field (like how Github does image uploading)?

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

http://www.dropzonejs.com/